# To prove the given inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, alternative-proof

**Question:-**

If $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers which are in H.P. show that $$\dfrac{a+b}{2a-b} + \dfrac{c+b}{2c-b} \ge 4$$

---

**Attempt at a solution:-**

I tried it by AM-GM inequality, but got stuck at a step. My attempt was as follows:-

$$\dfrac{ \dfrac{a+b}{2a-b} + \dfrac{c+b}{2c-b}}{2} \ge \sqrt{\dfrac{a+b}{2a-b} \cdot \dfrac{c+b}{2c-b}}$$

Evaluating the right hand side of the inequality,

$$\left(\dfrac{a+b}{2a-b} \cdot \dfrac{c+b}{2c-b} \right) = \left( \dfrac{b^2+\left(a+c \right)b+ac}{b^2-2b\left(a+c \right)+4ac}\right)$$

Now, as $a,b,c$ are in H.P., hence we get the relation $$b=\dfrac{2ac}{a+c}$$ On substituting this result in the equation, we get

$$\dfrac{10 a^2c^2 + 3ac(a^2+c^2)}{4a^2c^2}=\dfrac{5}{2}+\dfrac{3(a^2+c^2)}{4ac}$$

Now from the above calculations, what I observed is that, that for the proof to be valid, the condition $\dfrac{3(a^2+c^2)}{4ac}=\dfrac{3}{2}$ should be satisfied. The final conclusion to which I arrived was $a=c$. Now although the numbers would still be in H.P. but it doesn't prove the result for the numbers which are in H.P. and are not equal.

---

Any other approach to the proof is invited too.

Comment: Well, isn't it Harmonic Progression

Comment: yes, given that b = (2ac)/(a+c), this name makes sense

Comment: @DietrichBurde Well...is it a joke?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Don't we commonly use the abbreviations-AP,GP and HP.....(I do)...

Comment: @user350331: aren't you almost done? You just need to observe that (a^2+c^2)/(2ac) \geq 1 (because in fact it suffices 3(a^2+c^2)/(4ac)\geq 3/2)

Comment: @amakelov Oh!! I was indeed very close. So all i just had to do was prove that the $GM \ge 4$ and then use the AM-GM inequality. Thanks a lot. BTW, can you recommend me some books for the sake of improving my ability to solve inequalities.

Comment: @amakelov Can you also suggest an alternative proof.

Comment: back when i was preparing for math olympiads, i found this book useful: https://www.normalesup.org/~kortchem/olympiades/Cours/Inegalites/tin2006.pdf

Comment: @amakelov Can you please suggest an alternative proof too. I would be really grateful.

Comment: yup im writing it up right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, why don't we rewrite the HP condition in a nicer way, as 
$$\frac{2}{b} = \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{c}$$
and let's multiply the numerator and denominator of the first fraction by $2/b$. We get
$$ \frac{a+b}{2a-b} = \frac{a(1/a+1/c)+2}{2a(1/a+1/c)-2} = \frac{3+a/c}{2a/c}=\frac{3c+a}{2a}$$
Similarly, the other one becomes $\frac{3a+c}{2c}$, so what we want to show reduces to
$$\frac{3c+a}{2a} + \frac{3a+c}{2c}\geq 4$$
which reduces to
$$\frac{c}{a}+\frac{a}{c}\geq 2$$
which follows directly from AM-GM.

Answer (score 2):

The theorem you are asked to prove is not true in general. The additional condition needed is that $a \geq b$.  And then you can do the proof without AM-GM.

Assuming $(a,b,c)$ are in H.P. in the order $$a = \frac{1}{x}, b = \frac{1}{x+d}, c = \frac{1}{x+2d}$$
then the LHS is
$$
\frac{4x^2+8dx+6d^2}{x^2+2dx}
$$
Consider the case of $x^2+2dx > 0$:
$$
\frac{4x^2+8dx+6d^2}{x^2+2dx}-4 = \frac{1}{x^2+2d}\left[4x^2+8dx+6d^2 - 4(x^2+2dx) \right] = \frac{6d^2}{x^2+2d} \geq =0
$$
Now consider the case where  $x^2+2dx < 0$ and $d\neq 0$:
$$
\frac{4x^2+8dx+6d^2}{x^2+2dx}-4 =  \frac{6d^2}{x^2+2d} < 0
$$
So a good counterexample would be $x=3, d=-1$, giving $a=\frac13, b = \frac12, c=1$.

If you add the condition that $a\geq b$ then you find that forces $x^2 + 2dx \geq 0$ and the statement then is true.

Comment: I think the question has already forced the condition $x^2+2dx \gt 0$, because if so is not the case then the number $c$ comes out as negative which can't be accepted as per the question. Also, from the condition $a \ge b$, we get $d \ge 0$, which doesn't seem to be a necessary condition as illustrated in your countew example. So, I think the question has no loopholes.